# How to center headings on Dev Express grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

IN following Dev Express grid, they want to have the headings centered, currently they are siding to left side. How do you center "Facility" "State" etc.?

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="grid"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Summary}">
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Facility"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.Column="0"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.Row="0"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.RowSpan="2"
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource productHeader}" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="State"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.Column="1"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.ColumnSpan="3"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.IsBand="True"
                            HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center"
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource productHeader}" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="CNA"
                            EditSettings="{StaticResource TimeSpanEditSettings}"
                            FieldName="StateAide"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.Column="1"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.Row="1"
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource productHeader}" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="LPN"
                            EditSettings="{StaticResource TimeSpanEditSettings}"
                            FieldName="StateLpn"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.Column="2"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.Row="1"
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource productHeader}" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="RN"
                            EditSettings="{StaticResource TimeSpanEditSettings}"
                            FieldName="StateRn"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.Column="3"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.Row="1"
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource productHeader}" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Federal"
                            FieldName=""
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.Column="4"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.ColumnSpan="3"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.IsBand="True"
                            HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center"
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource productHeader}" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="CNA"
                            EditSettings="{StaticResource TimeSpanEditSettings}"
                            FieldName="FederalAide"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.Column="4"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.Row="1"
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource productHeader}" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="LPN"
                            EditSettings="{StaticResource TimeSpanEditSettings}"
                            FieldName="FederalLpn"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.Column="5"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.Row="1"
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource productHeader}" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="RN"
                            EditSettings="{StaticResource TimeSpanEditSettings}"
                            FieldName="FederalRn"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.Column="6"
                            dxg:BandedViewBehavior.Row="1"
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource productHeader}" />
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this in WPF and setting HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment achieved the result. Perhaps something in your template is overriding that? Does it work if you remove the template? If so, try setting that property in the template.